# Saving data in a .mat file using a for loop using python

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to store data in a .mat file using python. The data, an array is updated at each iteration of the for loop. I have trouble achieving this. The code and the error are as attached.

```
    from array import *
    import scipy.io

    a={}
    b=[9,8,7,6]
    i=0
    for i in range(10):
        a['m']=b.append(i)
        scipy.io.savemat('test.mat',a)
        i+=1
```

The error I get:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Python27/tryin", line 15, in <module>
         scipy.io.savemat('test.mat',a)
    File "C:\Users\rlangari\Portable Python 2.7.6.1\App\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\matlab\mio.py", line 204, in savemat
    MW.put_variables(mdict)
    File "C:\Users\rlangari\Portable Python 2.7.6.1\App\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\matlab\mio5.py", line 872, in put_variables
    self._matrix_writer.write_top(var, asbytes(name), is_global)
    File "C:\Users\rlangari\Portable Python 2.7.6.1\App\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\matlab\mio5.py", line 622, in write_top
    self.write(arr)
    File "C:\Users\rlangari\Portable Python 2.7.6.1\App\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\matlab\mio5.py", line 643, in write
    % (arr, type(arr)))
    TypeError: Could not convert None (type <type 'NoneType'>) to array
```

Comment: `a['m'] = b.append(i)` is equivalent to `b.append(i); a['m'] = None`. What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: This is a simple program to see if I can continuously add data to an already existing array and if the same can be read in MATLAB as and when the array is updated. So, to the array a stored in the mat file .mat, I am assigning the array b and also appending data to it in each iteration.

Comment: Thank you, I realized my mistake. I now append an element to the array b and then assign it to a rather than b.append(i).It would be nice if I could learn of a better way to transfer data between Python and MATLAB. I read data from a USB device using python and use them as inputs to the model in Simulink. I want simultaneous data transfer between the two.

Comment: `scipy.io` is meant to work with `numpy` arrays, not with `array` arrays.  It's the `numpy` ones that are similar to MATLAB matrices.  Append is not an efficient operation with `numpy` arrays.  Regular Python lists are better for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
b.append(i)
```

returns nothing. therefore each time you're getting an exception.

Comment: Thank you, I realized my mistake. I now append an element to the array b and then assign it to a rather than b.append(i).